# How to get an item from the webpage using php?

Tags: php

I want to get the data from a website, therefore I created the code below in php. The content which I want to get is inside a `<div>`:

```
<div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
    // Content I want to get 
</div>
```

My PHP code is as follow:

```
 <?php
    $page = file_get_contents('http://somewebsite.com');

    preg_match_all("/<div class=\"post-text\" itemprop=\"text\".*div>/", $page, $agent_name);

    print_r($agent_name);
?>
```

But when I execute the code, it does not show anything on the page. The output I get is like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476

Comment: so what should i use??

Comment: you should use a dom parser, they have been written to do such things. OR take a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and add the `m (PCRE_MULTILINE)` flag....

Comment: *"Have you tried using an X(HT)ML parser instead?"*

Comment: no how to use it?? never heard of it..

Comment: Now you can't say you haven't anymore - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For matching multiple lines of text, i usually use the PCRE_DOTALL modifier - using the pattern `"/<div class=\"post-text\" itemprop=\"text\".*div>/s"` instead of `"/<div class=\"post-text\" itemprop=\"text\".*div>/"` (just add the **s** at the end of your pattern) should give you the expected result.